# Different class or type of a variable after using $ in R

Tags: r

I have a small dataframe:

```
teams <- c("PHI","NYM","FLA","ATL","WSN")
wins <- c(92, 89, 94, 72, 59)
defeats <- c(70, 73, 77, 90, 102)

df <- data.frame(teams, wins, defeats)
```

And I would like to know the type and class of any value inside a dataframe.

When I use the class and typeof methods and reference the variable name using the dollar sign I get same result for **nleast$teams**: a factor.
Why is teams a factor and not a character type?

```
class(nleast$teams)
# factor
typeof(nleast$teams)
# factor
```

When I use just the name of the variable without a dollar sign I get **character** type and class for **nleast$teams**.

```
typeof(teams)
# character
 class(teams)
# "character"
```

I would like to know why I get different results when I use $ or just the name of the variable?

Thank you

Comment: `data.frame` by default converts characters to factors. Read `?data.frame` and note the `stringsAsFactors` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data.frame` function for making a new variable has an argument `stringsAsFactors`, which by default is `TRUE`. This means you'll convert `character` type variables to factor variables by default when creating a new data frame.

To correct this, simply change the call:

```
df <- data.frame(teams, wins, defeats)
```

to

```
df <- data.frame(teams, wins, defeats, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: This is clear so far. But why do I get different results from the class method if I use a dollar sigh or just the name of the variable?

Comment: @SchleiferGrigorij The answer literally explains that.

Comment: @SchleiferGrigorij `nleast$teams` and `teams` are two different objects, meaning they occupy different places in memory. For example, consider the results of `object.size(teams)` and `object.size(df$teams)`. The second is more than 2 times larger then the first (328B vs. 720B).

Comment: @SchleiferGrigorij You get different answers because you're referring to two completely separate variables. Once you create a data frame with the above call, R creates a copy of the data for use in the data frame. You're no longer referring to the old one with the `$` operator. 

You are probably confused because R uses the name of the old variable as the default name for the new column in the data frame. You can test that they're not referring to the same object in memory by changing a value of the original vector and examining the data frame. The data frame's copy will remain unchanged.

Comment: Thank you all guys. The answer and especially the last comment from **MentalOfDune** clears things up.